# Why do we use a t test when analyzing the estimate of a slope in a regression?

Tags: regression

I am reading some intro to statistics book and these passages came up:

[image]

and

[image]

and then,

[image]

So I see the estimated slope of the family-income is -0.04 and the standard error is 0.01 and the t-value is -3.98 implying that the null hypothesis is likely false.

My question is why we use a t-value instead of a z-value?

We have a sample, and n is fairly large. So why do we use t-values instead of z values?

Comment: The standard error of the coefficient is estimated and not known. With a large sample, t will be close to z but t is correct.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I know your answer is correct, but why?

Comment: The distribution of a statistic divided by an estimate of its standard error is, in general t. The only way I can think of to elaborate would be to show the mathematics for deriving  the distribution which is a bit complex.

Comment: @DavidLane do you know of a place that would describe these distributions, respecting the complexity? I often have been told to just treat t and z in regression, SEM, etc., outputs as all like t-statistics, since in both cases it is the estimate divided by the standard error. I'm wondering if writing all of them up as t-statistics is technically accurate or not.

Comment: They are t statistics.  In practice, you will probably never encounter a z in this context although you may for other statistical tests. So, yes, write them all up as t's.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that as n approaches infinite (or the population total with a parameter that is distributed along a z distribution), the T distribution converges to the Z distribution.Think of Z as the abstraction and T as the real world approximation.

Comment: This makes sense—do you know of any resources that explain it in more detail?

Comment: I personally am very fond of this chart: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/Relationships_among_some_of_univariate_probability_distributions.jpg

Comment: Interesting. So, when `lavaan` or `lmerTest` or `multcomp` give me estimates, SEs, and a "z-statistic" based on my sample, I should be reporting it as a *t*-statistic, because my sample in no way approaches an N of infinity (or, more appropriately, an N that encapsulates the whole population)?

Comment: oh, ok, I think I know what the issue you are facing is. For example, in lmerTest, they are not reporting a studentized t score but the Wald T. This is a non parametric T score.

Comment: Ah, okay. Would be nice if it were labeled better, but I'm sure (hopefully) it's all somewhere in the documentation of the various packages.